# ArrayList.remove gives different result when called as Collection.remove

Tags: java, collections, iteration

This code:

```
    Collection<String> col = new ArrayList<String>();    
    col.add("a");
    col.add("b");
    col.add("c");
    for(String s: col){       
       if(s.equals("b"))
             col.remove(1);  
       System.out.print(s);  

    }
```

prints: `abc`

Meanwhile this one:

```
    ArrayList<String> col = new ArrayList<String>();    
    col.add("a");
    col.add("b");
    col.add("c");
    for(String s: col){       
       if(s.equals("b"))
             col.remove(1);  
       System.out.print(s);  

    }
```

prints: `ab`

However it should print the same result...
What's the problem?

Answer (score 30):

`Collection` has only `boolean remove(Object o)` method, which removes the passed object if found.

`ArrayList` also has `public E remove(int index)`, which can remove an element by its index.

Your first snippet calls `boolean remove(Object o)`, which doesn't remove anything, since your `ArrayList` doesn't contain `1`. Your second snippet calls `public E remove(int index)` and removes the element whose index was 1 (i.e. it removes `"b"`).

The different behavior results from the fact that method overload resolution occurs at compile time and depends on the compile time type of the variable for which you are calling the method. When the type of `col` is `Collection`, only `remove` methods of the `Collection` interface (and methods inherited by that interface) are considered for overloading resolution.

If you replace `col.remove(1)` with `col.remove("b")`, both snippets would behave the same.

As Tamoghna Chowdhury commented, `boolean remove(Object o)` can accept a primitive argument - `int` in your case - due to auto-boxing of the `int` to an `Integer` instance. For the second snippet, the reason `public E remove(int index)` is chosen over `boolean remove(Object o)` is that the method overloading resolution process first attempts to find a matching method without doing auto-boxing/unboxing conversions, so it only considers `public E remove(int index)`.

Comment: Can you add the part about how the `Collections.remove()` method accepts an `int` due to autoboxing?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury sure

Comment: One more thing to add ArrayList is fail-fast collection, so if you are going to remove any element from list during traversing it than use CopyOnWriteArrayList, as it's fail-safe

Comment: Should also add that modifying a collection while iterating over it is in general a *bad idea*.  Some languages won't even allow it.  This is the reason you don't see the "c" being printed out.  It's still there (only the "b" was removed), but you've reached the "end" of your collection one step earlier because of the removal.

Answer (score 9):

To safely remove from a `Collection` while iterating over it, you should use an `Iterator`.

```
ArrayList<String> col = new ArrayList<String>();    
col.add("a");
col.add("b");
col.add("c");

Iterator<String> i = col.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   String s = i.next(); // must be called before you can call remove
   if(s.equals("b"))
      i.remove();
   System.out.print(s);
}
```

Regarding, the reason why removal from collection is not working for you while the `ArrayList` worked is because of the following:

1. The `java.util.ArrayList.remove(int index)` method removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Hence, this one worked for you.
2. The `java.util.Collection.remove(Object o)` method removes a single instance of the specified element from this collection, if it is present (it is an optional operation). More formally, removes an element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`, if this collection contains one or more such elements. Returns `true` if this collection contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this collection changed as a result of the call).

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Both snippets are broken in different ways!

*Case 1 (with `Collection<String> col`):*

Since a `Collection` is unindexed, the only `remove` method its interface exposes is [`Collection.remove(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-), which removes the specified equal object. Doing `col.remove(1);` first calls [`Integer.valueOf(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-) to get an `Integer` object, then asks the list to remove that object. Since the list does not contain such any `Integer` objects, nothing is removed. Iteration continues normally through the list and `abc` is printed out.

*Case 2 (with `ArrayList<String> col`):*

When `col`'s compile-time type is `ArrayList`, calling `col.remove(1);` instead invokes the method [`ArrayList.remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-) to remove the element at the specified position, thus removing `b`.

Now, why isn't `c` printed out? In order to loop over a collection with the `for (X : Y)` syntax, it behind the scenes calls the collection to get an `Iterator` object. For the `Iterator` returned by an `ArrayList` (and most collections) **it is not safe to perform structural modifications to the list during iteration** – unless you modify it through the methods of the `Iterator` itself – because the `Iterator` will become confused and lose track of which element to return next. That can result in elements being iterated multiple times, elements being skipped, or other errors. That's what happens here: element `c` is present in the list but never printed out because you confused the `Iterator`.

When an `Iterator` can detect this problem has happened it will warn you by throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException`. However, the check that an `Iterator` does for the problem is optimized for speed, not 100% correctness, and it doesn't always detect the problem. In your code if you change `s.equals("b")` to `s.equals("a")` or `s.equals("c")`, it does throw the exception (although this may be dependent on the particular Java version). From the [`ArrayList` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#fail-fast):

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator` methods are *fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis.

---

To remove elements during iteration, you must change the `for (X : Y)`-style of loop into a manual loop over an explicit `Iterator`, using its `remove` method:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = col.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String s = it.next();
    if (s.equals("b"))
        it.remove();
    System.out.print(s);
}
```

This is now completely safe. It will iterate all elements exactly once (printing `abc`), while element `b` will be removed.

If you want, you can achieve the same effect without an `Iterator` using an `int i`-style loop, if you carefully adjust the index after any removals:

```
for (int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++) {
    String s = col.get(i);
    if (s.equals("b")) {
        col.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
    System.out.print(s);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this. Also, `col.removeIf(s -> s.equals("b"))`.